# Why might FileOutputStream send excess bytes over a serial connection?

Tags: java

I am using FileOutputStream to send a string over out one serial port, and FileInputStream to read data in another serial port connected via a null modem.  It seems like FileOutputStream sends much more data than the length of the byte array passed to it.  I have verified that this is the case by watching the data using cat /dev/ttyUSB1.

If I use another bash terminal and do an echo 012345678u9ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ > /dev/ttyUSB0, there is no excess data sent.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class ExampleButtonGUI implements ActionListener {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JTextField text = new JTextField();
    private FileInputStream fis = null;
    private FileOutputStream fos = null;
    public ExampleButtonGUI() {
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("/dev/ttyUSB1");
            fos = new FileOutputStream("/dev/ttyUSB0");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        // the clickable button
        JButton button = new JButton("Send Data");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        // the panel with the button and text
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(text);

        // set up the frame and display it
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Serial Test");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // process the button clicks
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            int n = fis.available();
            if (n > 0) {
                byte[] bi = new byte[n];
                int br = fis.read(bi);
                String si = new String(bi, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
                System.out.println("RCV " + br + " bytes.\n" + si);
                text.setText(si);
            }
            String s = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\n";
            byte[] bo = s.getBytes();
            System.out.println("XMT " + bo.length + " bytes.\n" + s);
            fos.write(bo);
            fos.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    // create one Frame
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ExampleButtonGUI app = new ExampleButtonGUI();
    }
}
```

**The java app shows the following on the console as send button is hit.  Note that there are more bytes read then written at first, then things seem to work out.**

XMT 37 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

RCV 533 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF
XMT 37 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

RCV 1988 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
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
XMT 37 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

RCV 1237 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
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
XMT 37 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

RCV 483 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789ABCDE0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDE
XMT 37 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

RCV 37 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

XMT 37 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

RCV 37 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

XMT 37 bytes.
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

**The first time I hit the send button, this is what I see on the receiving bash terminal:**

0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDE0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

**Then as in the java app, things seem to start working on the bash terminal as well:**

0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not Java, this is a Unix problem.

/dev/tty* are pipes,

- there's no certainty that "one sent message" will be read in only "one read message". In your example, clearly the data is buffered in the pipe and the read all the packages in the same call.
- there's no concurrency control, so if several process write to the same tty the results are uncertain.

If you really want to communicate two process

- Use a fixed block size in both ends, and read and write only one that size.
- user a marker at the begin/end of the message, and make the reader split the response on that marker, and readmore if the last message is incomplete.
- Use your own pipes, if you can:

mkfile -p myPipe

Comment: I have written enough serial code to know that it may take multiple reads to get all the incoming data.  However, in this simple app, only one packet goes out for each button click, so I can't see how multiple processes can be writing to the tty.  When I comment out the code that reads /dev/ttyUSB1 in the java app, and instead launch bash cat, way more bytes come in than are passed to write(b[]).

I may crank up my logic analyzer to look at it, but I am convinced that what bash is displaying is correct.